# xlwings + Django: how to not loose a connection

Tags: django, xlwings

I am trying to deploy a spreadsheet model with a web page front end using Django. The web "app" flow is simple:

1. User enters data in a web form
2. Send form data to a Django backend view function "run_model(request)"
3. Parse request object to get user inputs and then populate named ranges in the excel model's input sheet using xlwings to interact with a spreadsheet model (sheet.range function is used)
4. Run "calculate()" on the spreadsheet
5. Read outputs from another tab in the spreadsheet using xlwings and named ranges (again, using sheet.range function).

The problem is that the connection to the Excel process keeps getting killed by Django (I believe it handles each request as a separate process), so I can get at most one request to work (by importing xlwings *inside* the view function) but when I send a second request, the connection is dead and it won't reactivate.

Basically, how can I keep the connection to the workbook alive between requests or at least re-open a connection for each request?

Comment: can you give any example code?

Comment: @denfromufa yea...ended up creating separate processes. See my self-posted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, ended up implementing a simple "spreadsheet server" to address the issue with Django killing the connection.

First wrote code for the server (server.py), then some code to start it up from command line args (start_server.py), then had my view open a connection to this model when it needs to use it (in views.py).

So, I had to separate my (Excel + xlwings) and Django into independent processes to keep the interfaces clean and control how much access Django has to my speadsheet model. Works fine now.

start_server.py

```
"""
Starts spreadsheet server on specified port

Usage: python start_server.py port_number logging_filepath
    port_number: sets server listening to localhost:<port_number>
    logging_filepath: full path to logging file (all messages directed to this file)
"""

import argparse
import os
import subprocess

_file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

#command line interface
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('port_number',
help='sets server listening to localhost:<port_number>')
    parser.add_argument('logging_filepath',help='full path to logging file (all messages directed to this file)')
    args = parser.parse_args()

#set up logging
_logging_path = args.logging_filepath
print("logging output to " + _logging_path)
_log = open(_logging_path,'wb')

#set up and start server
_port = args.port_number
print('starting Excel server...')
subprocess.Popen(['python',_file_path + 
  '\\server.py',str(_port)],stdin=_log, stdout=_log, stderr=_log)
print("".join(['server listening on localhost:',str(_port)]))
```

server.py

```
"""
Imports package that starts Excel process (using xlwings), gets interface
to the object wrapper for the Excel model, and then serves requests to that model.
"""
import os
import sys
from multiprocessing.connection import Listener

_file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(_file_path)
import excel_object_wrapper

_MODEL_FILENAME = 'excel_model.xls'
model_interface = excel_object_wrapper.get_model_interface(_file_path+"\\"+_MODEL_FILENAME)
model_connection = model_interface['run_location']
close_model = model_interface['close_model']

_port = sys.argv[1]
address = ('localhost', int(_port))     
listener = Listener(address)

_alive = True

print('starting server on ' + str(address))
while _alive:
    print("listening for connections")
    conn = listener.accept()
    print 'connection accepted from', listener.last_accepted

    while True:
        try:
            input = conn.recv()
            print(input)
            if not input or input=='close':
                print('closing connection to ' + str(conn))
                conn.close()
                break        
            if input == 'kill':
                _alive = False
                print('stopping server')                               
                close_model()
                conn.send('model closed')
                conn.close() 
                listener.close()
                break
        except EOFError:
                print('closing connection to ' + str(conn))
                conn.close()
                break 
        conn.send(model_connection(*input))
```

views.py (from within Django)

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import os

from multiprocessing.connection import Client

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def run(request):    
    model_connection = Client(('localhost',6000)) #we started excel server on localhost:6000 before starting Django
    params = request.POST
    param_a = float(params['a'])
    param_b = float(params['b'])        
    model_connection.send((param_a ,param_b )) 
    results = model_connection.recv()
    return render(request,'model_app/show_results.html',context={'results':results})
```